# Slider image fetching through XML in ColdFusion

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, coldfusion

I am trying to implement a slider in a coldfusion page & written jQuery script for fetching images through XML file. My XML file is including paths & other details of the Image. But it's not working, though it did for simple file on my WAMP server.
ColdFusion Code:

```
<cfoutput>
<script type="text/javascript" src="#request.serverCustom#rangers/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="#request.serverCustom#rangers/js/simplegallery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myArray = [];    
    $(document).ready(function() {
        alert("outside");
        $.ajax({
            //alert("ajax inside");
            type: "GET",
            url: "#request.serverCustom#rangers/js/sites.xml",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function(xml) {
                var count = 0;
                $(xml).find('site').each(function() {
                    var url = $(this).find('url').text();
                    var target = $(this).find('target').text();
                    var imageURL = $(this).find('imageURL').text(); 
                    var alt = $(this).find('alt').text();
                    myArray[parseInt(count)] = new Array(imageURL, url, target, alt); 

                    count++;
                });
                var mygallery2 = new simpleGallery({
                    wrapperid: "simplegallery2",
                    dimensions: [400, 240],                 
                    imagearray: myArray,                    
            autoplay: [true, 10000, 99], 
                    persist: true,
                    fadeduration: 1000, 
                    oninit: function() {
                    },
                    onslide: function(curslide, i) { 
                    }
                })                
            }
        });
alert(mygallery2);
    });
</script>
<div style="background: black none repeat scroll 0% 0%; overflow: hidden; 
position: relative; visibility: visible; -moz-background-clip: border; -moz-background-origin: 
padding; -moz-background-inline-policy: continuous; width: 400px; height: 265px;" id="simplegallery2"> 
</div>
</cfoutput>
```

My XML Code:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<sites>
  <site>
    <url><![CDATA[http://facebook.com]]></url>
    <target>_new</target>
    <alt>First Image : Random Image with Baloon(Will Go to FB)</alt>
    <imageURL><![CDATA[/img/Image1.jpg]]></imageURL>
  </site>

  <site>
    <url><![CDATA[http://google.com]]></url>
    <target>_new</target>
    <alt>Second Image : Random Image of a Toy(Will Go to Google)</alt>
    <imageURL><![CDATA[/img/Image2.jpg]]></imageURL>
  </site>

  <site>
    <url><![CDATA[http://twitter.com]]></url>
    <target>_new</target>
    <alt>Third Image : Random Image with Lighter with Water Filled</alt>
    <imageURL><![CDATA[/img/Image3.jpg]]></imageURL>
  </site>

  <site>
    <url><![CDATA[http://enablingdimensions.com]]></url>
    <target>_new</target>
    <alt>Fourth Image : A Image from Game(Will Go To Our Site)</alt>
    <imageURL><![CDATA[/img/Image4.jpg]]></imageURL>
  </site>

  <site>
    <url><![CDATA[http://ed.konnected.me]]></url>
    <target>_new</target>
    <alt>Fifth Image : A Cartoon in Yellow Background</alt>
    <imageURL><![CDATA[/img/Image5.jpg]]></imageURL>
  </site>

  <site>
    <url><![CDATA[http://yahoo.com]]></url>
    <target>_new</target>
    <alt>Sixth Image : Eating Fish with Anger(Will Go To Yahoo)</alt>
    <imageURL><![CDATA[/img/Image6.jpg]]></imageURL>
  </site>

</sites>
```

My folder "img" is located in the local path. Even I tried alert inside `$.ajax`, but it got break. I tried with fetching link image too, which worked with WAMP, but that also didn't work.
Any clue ?

Comment: Can you be a bit more descriptive of what's breaking? Also, are you able to navigate to the same URLs that your GET requests are making (use firebug or chrome dev tools to see the traffic)?

Comment: Nothing is breaking on to page but the images which should come in he slider is not coming.
When I tried putting alert inside the $.ajax, my previous given alert value also didn't come...and that why I said it's breaking.
I am not able to navigate to the link which GET request are making..may be because I am using remote server for putting these code & testing..so the address set in the variable is local for that but not for me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no ColdFusion code in your sample (apart from #request.serverCustom#). IN which case you don't need to bracket the whole dang script. Put outputs around just those variables as such.

```
<cfoutput>
<script type="text/javascript" src="#request.serverCustom#rangers/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="#request.serverCustom#rangers/js/simplegallery.js"></script>
</cfoutput>
```

And then inside the JS:

```
 type: "GET",
 url: "<Cfoutput>#request.serverCustom#</cfoutput>rangers/js/sites.xml",
```

Bracketing the whole thing will work, but it *seems* messier to me (although others will prefer it).

If you ARE having an issue with CF it is likely this var that is the issue. Load your page and go to "view source" - check out the HTML that is rendered. If the path to your jquery-1.3.2.min.js and simplgallery.jas files are screwed up then you need to fix it by adjusting the #request.serverCustom# variable - or by adding a slash or whatever.

I usually copy out from view source and load the path in my browser to see what I get (adjusting for relative vs absolute of course.

If it's something else I'm afraid we will need a bit more information. What is it actually doing?

Comment: I tried dumping the variable with my given path & it gave me - C:\iucn\iucn_assets\custom\rangers\js\simplegallery.js 

Though loading it into browser will give nothing as I am using remote server.
I am just starting into coldFusion..

Comment: There's your problem Rajeev :) A URL on a web page should look like either */js/simplegallery.js* or possibly a fully qualified URL with an http prefix. The *request.serverCustom" variable contains the physical path on the server - something that is not going to work to serve these files via HTTP. It needs to be replaced or altered till the path (in view source) is correct for the asset you are trying to serve. This is not really a ColdFusion issue.

Comment: If I am giving direct path for all these files which I have replaced on my server, then also it's working. I agree with you that it's not really a ColdFusion issue, but as I have just started with ColdFusion server & all these files I am trying to run on this server itself..that why still I am asking you to help... I didn't get any problem while I ran same thing with WAMP, which we I have used for PHP development..

Comment: no Rajeev... you can't use "direct path" (as in c:\blah or "\blah") doing so causes these files to be served using the FILE protocol instead of using the HTTP protocol. The only reason it would work on your WAMP stack is if you are developing *locally* - meaning the files exist on the machine in which the *browser* is running... but the file path on the server is not going to help the browser of a remote user... he or she needs an HTTP URL - NOT a file path.